# Prepopulate jquery datepicker gridview textbox with date value from querystring

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page called reserve.aspx with this markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Date" SortExpression="bookingDate">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="booking_id" runat="server" Target="_blank" HeaderText="Book Date" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("bookingDate","order.ashx?d={0}") %>' Text = 'Select' />
   </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When a user clicks **Select** and is redirected to order.asp page, we would like the value of **bookingDate** querystring to be populated in the datepicker control called txtdate below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("[id$=txtdate]").datepicker({

                showOn: 'button',

                buttonImageOnly: true,

                buttonImage: 'images/20/calendar200.gif'

            });
            $("[id$=txtdateReceived]").datepicker({

                showOn: 'button',

                buttonImageOnly: true,

                buttonImage: 'images/20/calendar200.gif'

            });

        });
```

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Event Date(s)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" style="width:95px;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdate"
                        ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

The user then has the option of using that date value or change it by selecting from the datepicker.

I have tried to capture the querystring value with the code below

```
Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(Gridview1.FindControl("txtDate"), TextBox)
tb.Text = Request.QueryString("d")
```

but I am running into:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* meaning that the value of the querystring is null.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this on RowDataBound event of the gridveiw1

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtDate"), TextBox)
        tb.Text = Request.QueryString("d")
    End If
End Sub
```